# Special characters don't show in AngularJS from input form, e.g. % & ? @

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, special-characters

I have an AngularJS form which show the password from an input box in a code snippet below the input box. But when the user enters any special character in the password, the password is not shown at all any longer, not even the non-special characters are then shown. Same result in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

The form script:

```
<script>
    angular.module('tutorialApp', [])
        .controller('TutorialController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.tutorial = {
                ipno: '123.456.7.8',
                sudouser: 'mysudouser1',
                dbname: 'mydb1',
                dbuser: 'mydbuser1',
                dbpw: 'mydbpassword',
                yourdomain: 'yourdomain.com',
                your2nddomain: 'test.yourdomain.com',
                name: 'name',
                word: /^\s*\w*\s*$/
            };
        }]);
</script>
```

Form input:

```
<label for="dbpw">Database password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="dbpw" ng-model="tutorial.dbpw" ng-pattern="tutorial.word" id="dbpw">
```

Code snippet:

```
<code>CREATE USER '<span class="frominput">{{tutorial.dbuser}}</span>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<span class="frominput">{{tutorial.dbpw}}</span>';</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `allowInvalid` in `ng-model-options`. Add this in the `input` - `ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"` Check this - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

```js
angular.module('tutorialApp', [])
        .controller('TutorialController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.tutorial = {
                ipno: '123.456.7.8',
                sudouser: 'mysudouser1',
                dbname: 'mydb1',
                dbuser: 'mydbuser1',
                dbpw: 'mydbpassword',
                yourdomain: 'yourdomain.com',
                your2nddomain: 'test.yourdomain.com',
                name: 'name',
                word: /^\s*\w*\s*$/
            };
        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="tutorialApp" ng-controller="TutorialController">
  <label for="dbpw">Database password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="dbpw" ng-model="tutorial.dbpw" ng-pattern="tutorial.word" id="dbpw" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true}">

  <br><br>
  
  <code>CREATE USER '<span class="frominput">{{tutorial.dbuser}}</span>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<span class="frominput">{{tutorial.dbpw}}</span>';</code>
</div>
```